# random forest error NA not permitted in predictors

Tags: r, random-forest

Hi I am using the following r script to build a random forest:

```
# load the necessary libraries                      
library(randomForest)


testPP<-numeric()


# load the dataset
QdataTrain <- read.csv('train.csv',header = FALSE)
QdataTest <- read.csv('test.csv',header = FALSE)

QdataTrainX <- subset(QdataTrain,select=-V1)
QdataTrainY<-as.factor(QdataTrain$V1)   

QdataTestX <- subset(QdataTest,select=-V1)
QdataTestY<-as.factor(QdataTest$V1)
mdl <- randomForest(QdataTrainX, QdataTrainY)
```

where I am getting the following error:

```
Error in randomForest.default(QdataTrainX, QdataTrainY) : 
  NA not permitted in predictors
```

however i see no occurence of NA in my data.

for reference here is my data:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zUFFsT01BYlRZU0E/edit
```

does anyone know why this error is being thrown? I'll keep looking in the mean time.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried the usual formula approach for calling modelling functions, ie `randomForest(V1 ~ ., data=QdataTrain)`? Does it give the same problem?

Comment: Try `traceback()` as well: run your script, and when it fails, type `traceback()` as the next command to see just what sub-command or function is throwing this error.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error (I commented all the test related data)

Comment: @e4e5f4 try this one https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zUFFsT01BYlRZU0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Indeed there are some missing values. I have shown steps to find them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given data does contain some missing values (7 in particular):

```
sapply(QdataTrainX, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

## V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 
## 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
## V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 
## 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Therefore columns V23 to V29 have one missing value each

```
which(is.na(QdataTrainX$V23))

## 318
```

Gives the row number for that.